# Antenna design for outdoor waterproof sensor

Tags: antenna, transmitter, 433mhz

[image]I am designing a low-cost soil moisture sensor with an RF433 radio. I put my sensor in a closed PVC tube for outdoor installation.(SIMILAR TO above image)

Without the tube, I can transmit nearly 300 m in line of sight, but when I put it inside the PVC tube (50 mm tube) for waterproof protection, I barely get 30 m.

My goal is 200 m. I use a spring antenna on the sensor.

Comment: You should adapt the length of the spring. Because of the permittivity of the box. Or use an external straight wire ("waterproof") of the "good" length ~ 23 cm).

Comment: The antenna used for cars seem to survive well in all elements : rain, sun, snow…

Comment: There is a test to see if the composition of the pipe is such that it will block HF: put a bit of pipe and a cup of water in a microwave oven. If the pipe heats up, it absorbs HF. All this at your own risk, of course. Or use an external antenna, and/or experiment with orientation.

Comment: https://forums.radioreference.com/threads/will-pvc-pipe-block-signal.252888/

Comment: It might be absorbing the RF, in which case you need different plastic. Or it might be detuning the antenna, in which case you need a larger diameter tube (to move it further away), or thinner walled tube (so there's less of it), or to retune the antenna on your radio to cope with the dielectric loading. Try putting it in a 2 litre PET drinks bottle.

Comment: You need to ask a question chamroeun bm

Comment: If you're looking for antenna options, you might tell us how much of that 50mm PVC tube sits below ground and how much is above ground...and add any constraints you have regarding antenna metal ABOVE the PVC tube. What diameter PVC tube?

Comment: Generally, plastics shouldn't block RF signals much. Though if you have positioned the antenna in some strange way in relation to metal parts (like in parallel with them), then that will affect the range a lot. If this lid is in metal then consider a whip antenna or similar pointing downwards inside the tube, away from the lid.

Comment: @glen_geek it's a soil sensor, so it's just 5 cm above ground. The tube diameter is 2".

Comment: @Lundin it's a PVC pipe around 2mm thick. There're 3 AAA batteries inside.

Comment: Those batteries are significant conductors inside. Proximity to antenna should be avoided- those batteries might be used as a counterpoise to the antenna radiator, which should likely extend *above* this PVC tube. Perhaps a half-wave vertical whip (about 30cm)? A half-wave radiates at very low angles close to ground.

Comment: @glen_geek I am a rookie on this telecom thing, I can't fully understand your suggestion. You mean antenna should be outside the PVC?